# Angular: Page is not displayed correctly

Tags: css, angular

I have a page on my website that is not displayed correctly:

Screenshot:
[image]

If I resize my browser window, the page will suddenly be displayed correctly.

Screenshot:
[image]

I had this effect once with a Datatable. I could solve it by inserting the resize event in the onInit method:

```
setTimeout(() => {
   window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
}, 500);
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work in this case. Does anyone have an idea how I can fix the problem?

I testet also in firefox instead of chrome. Firefox displays it correctly.

I use a mat-grid-list. when i remove the `rowHeight="255px"` it works fine but i cant set height with css.

Edit: i have changed rowHeight to 400px and it works. But if i use a smaller value the effect will reappear

I have tried to reproduct in stackblitz but there work all fine. also with rowHeight 250px

Comment: Can you please add the code relating to the problem to your question? When doing so, consider following this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: looks like css issue in my opinion,try setting 100% width and height in parent-container element in your component.

Comment: Do you have any errors in console?

Comment: @Abu Taha: i have tried but it dosn't work. if i set width and height in the devconsole, its display correct but but when i write in the scss It has no effect.

Comment: @Walter Łuszczyk: i dont have any errors.

Comment: @Rashad Saleh: i haven't had any success reproducing this in stackblitz yet :-(

Comment: Try to set absolute dimensions such as 500px.

Comment: @Abu Taha: also no effect. If i remove and add in devconsole (checkbox uncheck, check) it's work.. strange.. and I have now tried firefox instead of chrome, in Firefox it works fine

Comment: Try reproducing this in stackblitz so we can debug.

Comment: now i have found this in angular issuetracker:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/2497
I think its a issue with ui-grid (I used angular materials grid)